# Can't set SelectedValue in combobox using objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code :

```
public partial class ModificarAlimento : Form
{
    private Alimento alim;
    private Dictionary<string, Nutriente> nutrientes;

    public ModificarAlimento(Alimento a, Dictionary<string, Nutriente> nut)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.nutrientes = nut;
        alim = a;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CantidadNutrientes> x in alim.Nutrientes) 
        {
            ComboBox n = new ComboBox();
            n.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            n.Location = new Point(12, 25 * (i + 1) + 80);
            n.DataSource = new BindingSource(nutrientes, null);
            n.DisplayMember = "Key";
            n.ValueMember = "Value";
            TextBox cNuts = new TextBox();
            cNuts.Location = new Point(150, 25 * (i + 1) + 80);
            cNuts.Size = new Size(50, cNuts.Size.Height);
            cNuts.Text = x.Value.Cantidad.ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(n);
            this.Controls.Add(cNuts);
            i++;
            n.SelectedValue = x.Value.Nutriente;
        }
    }

    private void ModificarAlimento_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Now. The problem is here:

```
n.SelectedValue = x.Value.Nutriente;
```

Each `Alimento` (Food) has a dictionary set of `CantidadNutrientes`, which stores a double value and a `Nutriente` (Nutrient), which in turn stores a name. So, calling

```
x.Value.Nutriente
```

will retrieve the Nutriente in the CantidadNutrientes stored in x.

Why isn't this working? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm also trying this

```
n.SelectedIndex = n.FindStringExact(x.Key);
//and
n.SelectedValue = n.FindStringExact(x.Value.Nutriente.Nombre);
```

However for some weird reason it works while I debug, but if I don't go through line for line it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
n.CreateControl();
```

before this.Controls.Add(), and put

```
n.SelectedItem = 
  n.Items
   .Cast<KeyValuePair<string, Nutriente>>()
   .SingleOrDefault(o => o.Key == x.Key);
```

after call to this.Controls.Add()

Comment: You're welcome, I edited it not to use Items.IndexOf because it's simpler this way.

Answer (score 2):

You must use [`ComboBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) or [`ComboBox.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx):

```
combox.SelectedIndex = combox.FindStringExact("yourItem");
```

or

```
combox.Text = "yourIetmText";
```

**note that:**

[`ComboBox.FindStringExact Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact.aspx) can help you to finds the item index that exactly matches the specified string.

Comment: I believe you meant `ComboBox.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Either way doesn't work. I can't set the text (it's a DropDownList) and I can't select the index (I'm working with a dictionary so I have no information on "which number" is each entry).

Comment: When I go through line by line while debugging it, this works, but if I execute it without debugging it just doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Please use comboBox1.SelectedText instead this set the item and plus show as edited text in the combo

Comment: `n.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;` Hence I cant.